# .NET Core 2 Persistent Project References

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2 solution with a number of projects.

I'm reorganising some code and have run into a very odd scenario.  My API project had a reference to a library containing a class called `IMyService`.

This reference has been removed but the project can still "see" the `IMyervice` interface. The API does have a reference to a project that in turn *does* reference the `IMyService` project.

In "normal" .NET land I'd expect a compiler error given the scenario above.  Why is the .NET Core API project still able to see a class in a project it doesn't directly reference?

Comment: Transitive references, basically. (And boy do they make everything simpler.) I'm not adding an answer as there's a duplicate question that I'll try to find now.

Comment: Wow, OK.  Never encountered them before, time to learn a new thing!